# Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate : Insert and fetch list of entities at once

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using`Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate`. I have entity/table User. How to create `CrudRepositoty` to insert list of users at one time ? Also how to get the results as list for some query ?

Answer (score 0):

Make an **interface** that implements crudRepository.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long>  {



     List<User> findAll();

}
```

Here CrudRepository implicitly creates queries for your custom functions like findAll() in above code

**Service Class**

```
@Service("userservice")
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo rep;

    @Transactional
    public ArrayList<User> findAll()
    {

        return (ArrayList<User>) rep.findAll();

    }
}
```

In the same way you can save your object as rep.save(User object)

Comment: Thanks Vikram. One clarification , to get list of users having same name method would be List<User> findByName(String name) . Am i right ?

Comment: Thanks all. How to the get the number of Users with same name ?

Comment: Do some research you will get it on internet:)